# What do you call this tiny popup that appears at the bottom of the android screen called?

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications, popup

This might be a stupid question but I am new to android terms.

[image: This appears at bottom of screen]

I have seen this many times and I want to use this as a notification method.
However, I don't know what this is called.

I searched something like:

"Android notification at bottom of screen"
"Android popup at bottom of screen"
"Android notification box"

I haven't gotten anywhere.
I hope to find out what is this called.

Comment: I think you are seeing: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: I don't get why the answers have a downvote. Fish, did you downvote them?

Comment: @Razgriz I didn't do any downvotes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This kind of notification is called Toast. If you want to use Toasts in your application, all you want to do is write a line of code

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), //Context
                   "This is my message", // Message to display
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT // Duration of the message, another possible value is Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show(); //Finally Show the toast
```